# Why putting anything (div, p, or just text) inside ion-item after ion-input is not showing?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

I have requirements to validate a simple form. Everything is working but I am facing a little issue with placing text messages in ionic 3 list item.
The `ion-item` contains `ion-input` element. if I put `div` below it which contain some text will not show but if I place that div outside the item then message shows up in DOM, in the prior case my message doesn't even exist in the DOM.

Below is the case where messages won't display

```
<ion-item margin-bottom>
            <ion-input type="text" name="serial_number" #serialNum="ngModel" minlength="3" placeholder="WELL ID" [(ngModel)]="well.serial_number"
              required>
            </ion-input>
            <div class="text-md-danger" no-padding *ngIf="serialNum.invalid && (serialNum.dirty || serialNum.touched)">
              <div no-padding *ngIf="serialNum.errors.required">
                <small>
                  Providing WELL ID is mandatory.
                </small>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="serialNum.errors.minlength">
                <small>
                  WELL ID must be at least 3 characters long.
                </small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ion-item>
```

In the following case messages will display but placing is not right and I want to avoid putting custom CSS to place my messages underneath that input field.

```
<ion-item margin-bottom>
        <ion-input type="text" name="serial_number" #serialNum="ngModel" minlength="3" placeholder="WELL ID" [(ngModel)]="well.serial_number"
          required>
        </ion-input>            
      </ion-item>
      <div class="text-md-danger" no-padding *ngIf="serialNum.invalid && (serialNum.dirty || serialNum.touched)">
          <div no-padding *ngIf="serialNum.errors.required">
            <small>
              Providing WELL ID is mandatory.
            </small>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="serialNum.errors.minlength">
            <small>
              WELL ID must be at least 3 characters long.
            </small>
          </div>
        </div>
```

does anyone know why elements below `ion-input` inside `ion-item` are not showing?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things that are not normally part of `ion-item`, needs to be tagged with `item-content`, so you need to add that tag to your wrapping div:

```html
<div item-content *ngIf="....">
```

and then it should work like a charm! :) **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-2mrnwm?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)**

**EDIT**

We found out that you actually wanted to place the validation messages just beneath the fields, so that can be achieved by having a `ion-list inset` and marking the validation messages as separate `ion-item`:

```html
<ion-list inset>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" name="serial_number" #serialNum="ngModel" minlength="3" placeholder="WELL ID" [(ngModel)]="well.serial_number"
      required>
    </ion-input>            
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item class="text-md-danger" *ngIf="serialNum.invalid && (serialNum.dirty || serialNum.touched)">
    <small *ngIf="serialNum.errors.required">
      Providing WELL ID is mandatory.
    </small>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. my client wants it just underneath input field, I showed him, putting item-end attribute. It appears over the input.

Comment: You want something like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-bsmek5?file=pages/home/home.html With ion-list and ion-items.

Comment: item-content doesn't exist in Ionic 6.